# Como solucionar el trabajo de apache fallido

Tags: apache2

Estaba instalando apache2 en ubuntu 18.04 pero al momento de iniciarlo

**sudo systemctl start apache2.service**

Me  salió esto

**Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.**
**See systemctl status apache2.service and journalctl -xe for details.***
con **systemctl status apache2.servic**e revise el estatus y me marcó esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con **journalctl -xe** me sale lo siguiente

May 12 09:32:17 ubuntu systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpq3g.png): Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Ser

-- Subject: Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has finished start-up

-- Defined-By: systemd

The start-up result is RESULT.

May 12 09:32:17 ubuntu nm-dispatcher[4992]: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [ens33]: new re

May 12 09:32:17 ubuntu nm-dispatcher[4992]: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [ens33]: start

*Como puedo solucionarlo?*

Comment: Usa `journalctl -xe` y revisa con más detalle qué sale cuando intenta iniciar el apache. Luego, trae esos mensaje que encuentres (no TODO el log porque en el journal esta TODO de todos los procesos) y ponlo en la pregunta, como texto

Comment: Esas dos cosas que pusiste son de network manager, configurando tus interfaces de red... Hay que mirar con un poco más de cuidado porque, como te dije, está todo de todos. Intenta entonces ver si están los logs específicos de apache. Hasta donde recuerdo, está en `/var/log/apache2/`

Comment: Tengo access.log error.log y other_vhosts_access.log

Comment: Todos esos son logs de apache. error tiene errores, access tiene las peticiones que ha recibido, etc. Revísalos, dale espacio a la curiosidad. ¿No te da curiosidad ver qué dice ahí?